# Can't resolve android.support.design. after migration to AndroidX

Tags: android, textview, android-support-library, androidx, android-snackbar

I am trying to get the `TextView` of the `Snackbar` with this code snippet:

```
snackbarView.findViewById<TextView>(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text)
```

but Android Studio does not resolve the design library.

How can I get this code to work?

Comment: I have listed some of the correction to `Migrate-to-Android-X` problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54579196/2408879)

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Solved with this solution: `snackbarView.findViewById<TextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text)`

Comment: was struggling with this just now :)

Comment: @varun Thank you very much. Glad to help and give something back to the community!

Comment: @apurvthakkar NP. Glad I could help. Happy coding

Answer (score 54):

Thanks for the great answer by @dudi, in general in migration to androidX you can replace

`android.support.design.R`

with

`com.google.android.material.R`

I have written a brief step-by-step article on AndroidX migration [here](http://digigene.com/androidx-migration-in-a-nutshell-wolfcats), if someone is interested to know more.

Answer (score 15):

Changing this :

android.support.design.R

with

com.google.android.material.R

solves the problem .
After Migration to AndroidX we are working with different library.

Comment: Just a repetition of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

You've migrated to AndroidX, which means the library is different now.

(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text)
                 to 
(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text)

Comment: Sorry, but this is just a repetition of what the accepted answer states.

Answer (score 4):

As **android.support.design.R**
is no more supported after androidx migration,
So you need to replace it

with

**com.google.android.material.R**

Comment: Just a repetition of the accepted answer.