# AppBarLayout inflating error after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, migrate, android-appbarlayout

When migrating to `AndroidX` I faced this problem:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.mandarine.android/com.mandarine.android.features.root.RootActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18:
Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

Comment: Please show your build.gradle

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless you implement the old support libraries and enable Jetifier, you have to rename all your support classes in XML.

`android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` is now `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`.

You may need to use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'` in your build.gradle for this.

Look for any other Views in XML using the support library and rename the tags to match their AndroidX versions. You can simply search "ClassName AndroidX" in Google and you'll find the documentation for that class.

Comment: Thx, now we can use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` . But could you throw a link where i can find the name of the classes, as for example for `Space` again, I find it difficult to find. Perhaps somewhere there is a complete list of something like https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Like I said, you can just Google the class name followed by "AndroidX."

Comment: Ok, space became`( <androidx.legacy.widget.Space/>)`, as a bonus, you may be able to suggest and for `SwipeMenuRecyclerView`?

Answer (score 37):

I used AS 3.2 Migrate to AndroidX wizard. But it failed to migrate some classes. Below are some I have encountered on my project. The second entry is the correct one

```
android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialog
com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog 

android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout 

android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

androidx.core.view.ViewPager
androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior
com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior 

android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 

android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView

android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView 

androidx.appcompat.widget.CardView
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 

android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

androidx.core.view.ViewPager
androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

importandroidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout
androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 

androidx.appcompat.widget.RecyclerView
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView 

androidx.core.view.PagerAdapter
androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter

importandroidx.core.app.FragmentManager
importandroidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
```

Comment: Also you should replace these lines
`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` with `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton`

Comment: and also `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox` with `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox`.

Comment: Also for error `android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text` use `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`