# ANDROID: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, androidx

I added a toolbar to my layout and now I get this error when running:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/mainactivity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
```

This is my activity layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/appbar"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my appbar layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

In my activity onCreate():

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());
        }
```

I can't figure out why. Any suggestions?

Comment: try wrapping inside `CoordinatorLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout` . also i see you are missing constraint for your embedded layout

Comment: and also try replacing `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` with `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`

Comment: and also check if you have complete setup for migration https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: If you are using Android Studio's `Migrate to AndroidX` wizard, check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54579196/2408879)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to use

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Instead of

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Make sure u have added below `dependencies`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

**UPDATE**

if you have used `Toolbar` and `AppBarLayout` inside your activity then   make sure you have correct imports  inside your activity code

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
```

Comment: is it a MUST use com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout and
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar ? is it possible a solution support library?

Comment: @metis if you are using `androidx` `dependencies` then you need to use `<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout` and `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

Answer (score 7):

**@Nilesh** answer worked for me but there is more. For those who use androidx;

change these in your layout;

```
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

to this;

```
androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding further to @NileshRathod's answer, errors regarding inflating classes occur almost only due to incorrect dependencies in the app level `build.gradle` file.

You must add the following dependency in you app level `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Well, I suggest you to use `Material` or `AndroidX` dependencies