# Why is it giving me a "unfortunatley <app name > has ended" when I run the app on an external device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, mobile-application

im building an app in android studio, and on my MainActivity, i have a button that when clicked leads to another activity. However, when i ran it on the actual external device, I got the message that it has unfortunatley stopped. However, on the virtual device, it works perfectly fine. Does anyone know what's happening?

This Is my Main Activity Code

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView greeting;
    Button click;
    Button slope;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //when the surprise button is clicked
        greeting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVGreeting);
        click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                greeting.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //make the result visible
            }
        });
        //when the slope formula button is clicked
        slope = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slopeBtn);
        slope.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToMathGraphical(); //go to the slope Activity
            }
        });
    }

    //button goes to new activity.
    private void goToMathGraphical()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScrollMathGraph.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is the MainActivity XML file

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Welcome to the  Fornula App!"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.439"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.183" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClick"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="SUPRISE"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.455"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tV"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.728" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVGreeting"
        android:layout_width="224dp"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Good Morning"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnClick"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.44"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tV"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.525" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/slopeBtn"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="GRAPHICAL FORMULAS"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.46"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnClick"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.293" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the ScrollMathGraph class

```java
package com.example.formulaapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ScrollMathGraph extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button slope2d;
    Button distance2d;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll_math_graph);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Let us Know If we are missing any Formulas", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"xxxx@yahoo.com" , "xxx@gmail.com"});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "New Formula not in App");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Hello! please let us know what formula we are missing! Thank you!");
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(ScrollMathGraph.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        slope2d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Slope2D);
        slope2d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToSlopeActivity(); //go to the slope Activity
            }
        });
        distance2d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Distance2D);
        distance2d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToDistance2DActivity(); //go to the slope Activity
            }
        });
    }

    //button goes to new activity.
    private void goToSlopeActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ScrollMathGraph.this, SlopeFormula.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //button goes to new activity.
    private void goToDistance2DActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ScrollMathGraph.this, Distance2D.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

This is the ScrollMathGraph XML file

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScrollMathGraph">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/formulas"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="535dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2DTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" 2D Graphical Formulas "
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Slope2D"
                android:layout_width="112dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2D Slope"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="214dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Distance2D"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2D Distance"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="303dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Midpoint2D"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2D Midpoint" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" 3D Graphical Formulas"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Slope3D"
                android:layout_width="108dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3D Slope" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Distance3D"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3D Distance" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Midpoint3D"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3D Midpoint" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the error that I am getting

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.formulaapp, PID: 9888
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.formulaapp/com.example.formulaapp.ScrollMathGraph}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:663)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:739)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:520)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.formulaapp.ScrollMathGraph.onCreate(ScrollMathGraph.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:637)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:739) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:520) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.formulaapp.ScrollMathGraph.onCreate(ScrollMathGraph.java:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070063 a=-1 r=0x7f070063}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:173)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:637) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:739) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:520) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.formulaapp.ScrollMathGraph.onCreate(ScrollMathGraph.java:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I saw that this error pertained to one of the classes that I wrote

```
 at com.example.formulaapp.ScrollMathGraph.onCreate(ScrollMathGraph.java:19)
```

Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Check your logs, the answer is in

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this is my first app and I am fairly new to this. What exactly should I be looking for?

Comment: The crash you have. It must be a red stacktrace, with the Error Level

Comment: Thank you for that, I found the error. I have edited my post to contain the error along with the specific line that causes an error in the class that I wrote. However, I am confused as to why that is causing an error.

Comment: "XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout" so check out line 9 in your XML config. And google that error message. Have a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298742/android-error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-appbarlayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AppBarLayout` has a background drawable (`android:background="@drawable/formulas"`) and the error message says specifically

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070063 a=-1 r=0x7f070063}
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)

So since your app works fine on one device and crashes on another, it looks like you did not provide that drawable resource for every device type.

Without knowing more about your drawable resource folders, I can only suggest that you make sure that you have a version of the `formulas` drawable for every constellation.

More information on this topic can be found in the guide to [Providing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources)